# Unable to use chrono feature with diesel in Rust/Actix application

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am still quite a rookie on Rust.

I try to use NaiveDateTime in some of my diesel models.

Therefore I try to import chrono as an extern crate like this:

src/db/models.rs

```
extern crate diesel;
extern crate chrono;

use diesel::{sql_types};
use chrono;

// model implementations follow below ...
```

However I am getting a rust error saying:

```
can't find crate for `chrono`: can't find crate
```

chrono is declared as a diesel feature. My Cargo.toml looks like this:

```
[package]
name = "backend"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["My Name <my@emai.l>"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
actix-web="3"
diesel= { version = "1.4.5", features = ["mysql", "chrono"] }
dotenv= { version = "0.15.0" }

[[bin]]
name = "main"
path = "src/main.rs"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install `chrono` itself.

```
[dependencies]
actix-web = "3"
chrono = "0.4"
diesel = { version = "1.4.5", features = ["mysql", "chrono"] }
dotenv = { version = "0.15.0" }
```

Adding a `chrono` feature to `diesel` only makes `diesel` compile with a dependency on `chrono` and glue code to integrate it. However, to use `chrono` in *your own* crate, you still have to declare it in `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: But couldn't that be a source for version collisions i.e. inconsistencies? What if the chrono version declared by me in the Cargo.toml deviates from the version diesel installs as a feature?

Is there a way to monitor if the two versions are in sync?

Comment: @LongHike it could, but probably won't. Its a whole nother topic, but if two dependencies are "semver compatible" (1.1 vs 1.2), then cargo will build one version for both two use. If two dependencies have incompatible versions (1.1 vs 2.0), then cargo will build both of them to use independently. If diesel updates to an incompatible version of chrono, while you're making use of it, the compiler will be sure you let you know there's a problem.

Comment: To monitor duplicates I use [`cargo tree -d`](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-tree).

Comment: I am still getting error, `^^^^^^ could not find 'chrono' in 'diesel'` after adding to the diesel features.
How to you add to a file? I have tried, ` use diesel::chrono::*` and get that error.